# ¿Cómo actualizar campos en dos tablas a la vez (PGSQL)?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla `(usuario)` la cual tiene por ley `nombre`, `apellido`, `email` y `contrasena`, y otra tabla `(informacion_personal)` con muchas columnas (aproximadamente 20). Lo que sucede es que en una vista hago un `INNER JOIN` entre estas, la cual me lista el nombre y apellido y el resto de información tomada de la tabla 'informacion_personal'.

El problema es que si quiero, por ejemplo, actualizar mi nombre y/o apellido juntos con otros datos no puedo ya que debería de haber una sentencia que me deje actualizar los campos en ambas tablas pero no he podido.

Agradezco el interés por este tema que no me deja avanzar.

**CÓDIGO SQL**

```
  UPDATE 
    informacion_personal
  SET                                                
    tipodocumento = '$tipodocumento',
    numerodocumento = '$numerodocumento',
    departamento = '$departamento',
    ciudad = '$ciudad',
    direccion = '$direccion',
    barrio = '$barrio',
    estrato = '$estrato',
    nombrefamiliares = '$nombrefamiliares',
    cantidadhijos = '$cantidadhijos'
  WHERE
    id_informacion_personal = '$id_informacion_personal'
```

¿Cómo podría insertar la otra tabla en esta sentencia para actualizar el nombre o el apellido?

Comment: Debes hacer una transacción (meter las consultas entre un begin y un commit) para asegurarte que las dos consultas se realizan correctamente.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Comment: Otra solución sería mejorar tu modelo de datos.

Comment: ¿Puedes describir cuales son las claves primarias de ambas tablas, y la relación entre ambas tablas? o sea, ¿cual es la clave foránea, y si es que se trata de una relación 1-1, o 1-N, ?

Comment: Y se me olvidó la pregunta mas obvia: ¿hay alguna razón en particular por la que no puedes simplemente ejecutar 2 sentencias update una después del otro?

Comment: y de que que manera puedo realizar esas dos sentencias?...y la relacion que hay es de 1-1

Comment: No se mucho de php, pero aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacer una transacción.http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlphp/trans/

Answer (score 0):

Sé que esta pregunta es muy, muy antigua. Pero si llegas hasta aquí con la misma duda que yo: sí se pueden actualizar dos tablas a la vez utilizando una función con parámetros. En mi caso necesito actualizar el nombre de la compañía de un usuario pero a su vez ese usuario tiene proyectos que también almacenan el nombre de la compañía para temas de filtro. Pues la función me quedó así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_company_name(
    _actual_company_name character varying,
    _new_company_name character varying)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE users SET 
company_name=_new_company_name
WHERE company_name=_actual_company_name;
UPDATE projects SET 
company_name=_new_company_name
WHERE company_name=_actual_company_name;
IF FOUND THEN
        return 1;
    ELSE
        return 0;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Se debe tener en cuenta que solo usuarios con permisos de admin pueden modificar el nombre de la compañía, por eso modifico todos los campos que coincidan.

PD: la función está hecha en pgAdmin 4.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TRIGGER `ActualizarTablaDespues` AFTER UPDATE ON `tablaqueseactualizo`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE NombreDeTabla SET nombre=new.nombre ...
where id=old.id

END;//

Comment: Entiendo la idea que propones, pero toma en cuenta que el trigger que dispara después de un update de la primera tabla no tiene manera de obtener los datos necesarios para modificar la segunda tabla.  De cualquier forma, siempre es buena idea agregar aunque sea un poco de explicación para que se entienda el código. Y cabe mencionar también que esa no es la forma correcta de escribir un trigger en PostgreSQL. Tal vez tenías otro motor de base de datos en mente.

Comment: exacto, normalmente el trigger se ejecuta despues de; pero en este caso no necesito ejecutar una sentencia despues de, ya que se supone que deberia de ser una sentencia unica.

Comment: *ya que se supone que deberia de ser una sentencia unica*: @Daniel: Eso es lo que no entiendo. ¿Qué quieres decir por eso, que se supone que debe ser una sentencia única? ¿De donde viene aquella restricción?